# Where to recruit people for a roll for shoes game?

Tags: finding-other-players, roll-for-shoes

I am trying to gather people to host a game of roll for shoes but since i am not very familiar with the people who use the system i don't know where they hang at or how to contact them. Does anyone know where i can gather people with interest in roll for shoes mechanics?

To be more specific i am looking to create a roll for shoes game with the experience only being awarded by the GM. I plan to make it a west marches style campaign so i am not looking for those who just want to play a one shot.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen please don't use comments to answer a question, especially if it's on-hold/closed. Even a "pseudo-answer" is an answer and not what comments are to be used for.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question because I believe it has valid answers that would not be equally valid answers to the generic question it has been closed as a duplicate of. (Mods like @SevenSidedDie can see a rough sketch of such an answer in a deleted comment above.) Specifically, I would like to frame-challenge the OP's idea that "gather[ing] people with interest in [a specific system's] mechanics" actually is a good way to find players for beginner friendly microsystems like Roll for Shoes.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey: Better?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I agree with the answer you’re hinting at, but I don’t think a question merits re-opening just so it can be frame-challenged. To answer the question straight would mean duplicating the linked question. I think it should stay closed as a dupe.